# Access instance variable from View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activerecord

I have this call in my View:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/appointments",
      data: "dog_id="+ dog_id
    });
```

My route:

```
match '/appointments',  to: 'appointments#index', via: 'get'
```

Controller action:

```
def index
        @appointments = Appointment.where("dog_id = ?", params[:dog_id])
        @appointments = Appointment.all
    end
```

Both of these solution don't work. When I try to fetch events from appointment I receive a message:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm trying to get all appointments in View:

```
<% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Have you checked the value of params[:dog_id]? Is there a record with that dog_id?

Comment: You can make your code more concise, it's equivalent to `@appointments = Appointment.where(dog_id: params[:dog_id])`

Comment: even if there is no record with that dog_id, it should not receive NilClass, instead it will return an empty array.. Can u try change the instance variable name or just simply try the query line inside view.. just to make sure where the error could be..

Comment: How your view looks like? is it index.js.erb where you try to render some appointments? why are you fetching @appointments with params and right after that you are fetching all appointments

Comment: @MarekLipka - Logs say that action is not even firing.

Comment: @crazybob - Yes, there is a record with that dog_id.

Comment: IvanShamatov - It's not index.js.erb. It's one other view where I need to access new data after user chooses another item from one drop down menu. When I put @appointments = Appointment.all in controller of that view I receive all the data. I am not fetching both. Those were just tests to check, forgot to comment one before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this ajax call, json return a data, for this you not able to access directly in rails

so u can try the code like this,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/appointments",
  dataType: "json",
  data: "dog_id="+ dog_id,
  success:function(data){
     alert(data);
   }
});
```

that  'data' return like an [object Object] , You can loop it and get instance value

ex

> success(data){
>        var x = new Array();
>        alert("created new array");
>        for (var i=0;i
>        {
>          x[i] ,x[data[i].toString()]=function(){};
>        }      }

x returns a instance variable value now you can access it in your view.